# combobox in propertygrid using Extjs-6

Tags: extjs, combobox, propertygrid, extjs6

I'm Using [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic). I have `propertygrid`. One of this `propertygrid`'row is a `combobox`. `valueFiled` property of `combobox` is `id` and `displayfield` is `name`. When I want to edit the `combobox` in `propertygrid` it show the names, but when the `propertygrid` is not in edit mode, it show the `id`. I want to show in 2 modes `name` value, and its value be `id`.  My sampleCode is [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11f0).

**Is it possible**? **How Can I Do it**?

Comment: You can use a [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-cfg-sourceConfig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@CD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139300/cd) mentioned, you should use renderer:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
width: 400,
height: 200,
title: 'Its me!',
items: [{
    xtype: 'propertygrid',
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    source: {
        ali: 3
    },
    sourceConfig: {
        ali: {
            displayName: 'ali',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: store,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id'
            },
            renderer: function(v){
                return store.findRecord("id", v).get("name");
            }
        }
    }
}]
});
```